# Search Box not visible when i come from save edit page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search

When i edit the page and add a custom list web part in SharePoint 2013 and edit the web part go under Miscellaneous section and select 'Display search box' option. i am able to see the search box in the edit mode of the page. Once i save the page or publish the page. The search box is getting disappeared. WHY ???

Comment: is their any change to master page? another thing when you said published, is it approved & publsihed?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and it is a bug that is fixed in Service Pack 1.